# WinAPI write to PhysicalDrive

Tags: c++, winapi

Я пытаюсь писать информацию напрямую в диск. Имеется два хэндлера : _hFileSource, 
_hFileDest. 
_hFileSource - указывает на некоторый файл. _hFileDest - указывает на PhysicalDrive1(\\.\PhysicalDrive1)

```
_hFileSource = CreateFile(_sourcePath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, (_useSystemCache ? FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL : FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING), 0);
_hFileDest = CreateFile(_destPath, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, (_useSystemCache ? FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED : FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED), 0);
```

Пишу на диск я таким образом

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        _readFileSize += _blockSize;
        DeviceIoControl(_hFileDest, FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &status, NULL);
        SetLastError(0);
        SetFilePointer(_hFileDest, i*512, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
        WriteFile(_hFileDest, _cacheBuffer->GetBufferData() + i*512, 512, 0, NULL);
        DeviceIoControl(_hFileDest, FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &status, NULL);
        int test = GetLastError();
        _countBlock--;
        DeviceIoControl(_hFileDest, FSCTL_UNLOCK_VOLUME, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &status, NULL);
    }
```

При записи в test выдаёт ошибку 5. Если я буду писать только в первый сектор то ошибка будет отсутствовать. Но при этом всё время будет перезаписывать 1 сектор. Если использовать `SetFilePointer(_hFileDest, 0, NULL, FILE_CURRENT)` тогда получается что я имею доступ только 1 сектору. Как мне можно записать информацию в остальные сектора?

Comment: GetLastError для кого придумали?

Comment: Приведите значение `GetLastError()`

Comment: А в чем смысл вызывать GetLastError после трех API, если вы не проверяете код возврата ни для одной из них? Может, у вас не WriteFile отваливается, а DeviceIoControl.

Comment: Просто все ошибка падает именно после WriteFile